# TransitGatewayRouteTableId for default TransitGatewayRouteTable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, transit-gateway

I am using the following settings for creating a transit gateway through CloudFormation.

```
AutoAcceptSharedAttachments: disable
DefaultRouteTableAssociation: enable
DefaultRouteTablePropagation: enable
```

I want to know how can one get the "TransitGatewayRouteTableId" in this situation? It is a necessary property for creating a static route in the **default** transit gateway route table.

```
Type: AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRoute
Properties: 
  Blackhole: Boolean
  DestinationCidrBlock: String
  TransitGatewayAttachmentId: String
  TransitGatewayRouteTableId: String
```

I have already tried the following `!GetAtt` intrinsic function but it doesn't work since it seems that the only return value for a transit gateway resource is the `id` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-transitgateway.html

`TransitGatewayRouteTableId: !GetAtt TransitGateway.AssociationDefaultRouteTableId`

Answer (score 5):

Thats an annoying limitation of the `AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRoute` resource you will have to write a custom resource using a lambda function to retrieve `AssociationDefaultRouteTableId`, use the transit-gateway id value and pass it into custom resource lambda. If you're going to use python use describe-transit-gateways method https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_transit_gateways

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html